# How do I eject the DVD from the macbook pro 10.5 in the CLI?

Tags: macbook, osx-leopard

I have a DVD in my macbook pro with 10.5 but I can't find the eject button in the finder.  Holding the physical eject button on the keyboard doesn't do anything.  Is there a CLI way to eject the DVD or an alternate GUI method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
drutil eject
```

Comment: It's not working, any other suggestions?

Comment: If nothing of the above works, consider the idea that your drive might be malfunctioning. Are you actually 100% sure there is a disk in the drive?

Comment: It looks like this command made DVD volume and the the eject button appear again in the finder.

Comment: @thierry Great it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Under "alternate method", press and hold the mouse button while the system is booting up (turn computer off, press mouse, turn computer on, wait for cd). The *only* time this hasn't worked for me is when one of the internal connectors was not seated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VMWare Fusion or any other "dual computer" software, the "other" computer may have ownership of the drive.  In my case, switching to the Windows machine and ejecting the DVD from there was the answer.